# Conditions under which there can be group action of $D_4$ on the set of $2$-colorings of a regular hexagon.

Tags: group-actions, group-homomorphism

Have been in a course on group theory, and was hinted that there can be a group action by $D_4$ on the set of $2$-colorings of a hexagon.

But, that implies a homomorphism between the two groups $D_4, D_6.$
*(This is [shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4572585/424260) by failure , by me to have a group action in the second table, due to the overlap of two orbits : $\mathcal O_6, \mathcal O_7$)

It is justified, in the **Edit**, by the failure of homomorphism between the two groups: $D_4, D_6$)*

Hence, does it imply that the question can be changed to: 
Under what conditions is it possible to define homomorphism between the two dihedral groups: $D_4, D_6?$

Kindly give hints, by providing under what conditions is it possible to have the needed group action.

Or, is it that have construed the hint wrongly?

Comment: What do you mean "under what conditions"? You are referring to two specific groups: either there exists a homomorphism $D_4 \to D_6$ or there does not. In fact, there are exactly $40$ such homomorphisms.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Please give reference as where to find such homomorphisms, as then my link above is wrong in showing under 'Edit', no homomorphism.

Comment: Here is the simplest example: if $G$ and $H$ are any groups, then the function $f : G \to H$ defined by $f(x) = e$ is always a homomorphism (here $e$ is the identity element of $H$). This is called the *trivial homomorphism*. So in your case, there is a homomorphism $D_4 \to D_6$ given by sending every element of $D_4$ to the identity element of $D_6$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Am confused about my link's edit then. Please tell what is wrong about that, as it shows a lack of homomorphism by taking a special case of $G= D_6,$ by taking two symmetries $g_1= r^5, g_2= r^3$ and $\phi(g_1\times g_2)= r^2,$ while the map to group $J= D_4,$ yields $\phi(g_1)\star \phi(g_2)= r\star r^2= r^3.$

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Also, tell (or hint, or provide reference) how the computation of the number of homomorphisms from $D_4\to D_6$ is $40?$ There are eight elements in $D_4.$ That means map is possible to only a subset of $D_6.$ But, not clear how a value of $40$ is arrived at. You have provided one homomorphism by mapping each element of $D_4$ to the identity element of $D_6.$